# Windows 8 does not provide option to choose which user have to login at welcome screen like Windows 7

Tags: windows-8, user-accounts, login-screen

I'm using Windows 8 Enterprise trial edition and its work good. But there is one option which is bothering me that doesn't ask me to choose which user have to login at welcome screen like Windows 7.

I have to sign out from the current user to login in other account. However I can login in other account without sign out but its not what I'm looking for.

[image]

I can switch the user by clicking on my account and then click on the account in the list. But I want to show up the Windows 8 to let me choose the account I want to login at welcome screen.

**Note**: Both accounts has the privileges of Admin.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 8 believes that the same user who shut down the computer will start it.
Try the back button on the left side.
As you haven't mentioned logging in, It could be that you are using a local account and it is logging you in directly.

Comment: just what I want, a computer making assumptions for me. Actually it may have to do with hybrid shutdown, Microsoft is obsessing with super fast boot times.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a technique I used to achieve the reverse - hide users from the Welcome Screen in Windows 7.  However, there is a 50% chance you could modify it to achieve what you want and show users in Windows 8.

1. Navigate to the Winlogon section of the registry, to be precise:

   ```
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
   ```
2. Create a Key called `SpecialAccounts`  (note plural). Then create a sub-key called `UserList` (note singular no spaces)
3. You should have:

   ```
   Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList
   ```

   Now create a DWORD (32-bit) Value with the same name as the user that you wish to hide, if you remember I called my account 'Eddie'.
4. I now have `Winlogon\SpecialAccounts\UserList\Eddie` With a RegDword Value (1)
   Zero means hide, one would mean show.

(I don't have a Win8 machine to test right now)

Comment: I did the same as you suggested but no luck.

Comment: It worked only after I logged out from my current session